# unable to create a release version of xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I was trying to create a release version of xamarin with a built-in project, but I encountered an error like below.

> Fast Deployment is enabled for 'App1.Android'.
>
> The selected build configuration is using a Debug-only feature for
> faster deployment. Apps cannot be archived with this setting enabled.
>
> Please ensure that you are using a release configuration and that the
> "Use Fast Deployment" option in your project's build options is
> unchecked.

How's the solution?

Comment: That error tells you exactly what to do. Have you tried that?

Comment: like that? https://postimg.cc/LgfZ4K4N

if yes, i was try, but It's the same

Comment: The error tells you to turn that off...

Comment: i was try to turn off and turn on, but it's the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this bug, i was try to restart visual studio 2019, but the configuration "Use Fast Deployment" is checked, even though I have turned off and I ctrl + s, after that I try to turn it off again and restart it again, the new configuration can be stored correctly